# Realm Swift changing the data type of a named variable

Tags: ios, swift, realm, database-migration

I have experience with Realm migration so I know a little about it.

Anyways to explain my situation I have a variable named `phoneInfo` that was of a type `PhoneInfo` but the Android developer changed things up on me and now I need it to be of type `String`.

So to put it more straight forward I had this:

```
public class TestResult:Object{
    @objc dynamic var id:String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var phoneInfo:PhoneInfo = PhoneInfo() //before change
    override class public func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" }
}
```

But, now I need this:

```
public class TestResult:Object{
    @objc dynamic var id:String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var phoneInfo:String = "\(PhoneInfo().BaseOS)" //after change
    override class public func primaryKey() -> String? { return "id" }
}
```

I can't find it in the Realm Documentation although I will keep looking. I found this Github [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1311) that describes my problem. However, I am having trouble translating the objective-c into Swift4.

Here is my PhoneInfo Object:

```
public class PhoneInfo:Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var BaseOS:String = UIDevice.current.systemName
    @objc dynamic var OsVersion:String = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
    @objc dynamic var Manufacturer:String = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
    @objc dynamic var Model:String = UIDevice.current.model
}
```

This is how I am trying to migrate data right now in my AppDelegate.swift.

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 6,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 6) {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: TestResult.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    //changed
                    let phoneInfo = oldObject!["phoneInfo"] as! PhoneInfo
                    newObject!["phoneInfo"] = "\(PhoneInfo().BaseOS)"
                }
            }
    })
    let r = try! Realm()
```

Any help is welcome. I will be trying to solve it myself of course and will post it if I do.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current implementation? What errors do you receive? Btw your old implementation was flawed, one-to-one relationships need to be optional. `@objc dynamic var phoneInfo:PhoneInfo?` is the correct implementation. Btw storing static information in a database, such as `UIDevice.current.systemName` doesn't really make sense unless you are storing logs for a long time and need to keep a log of the property changing.

Comment: Hey @DávidPásztor thank you for your advice. I am doing this because our app we are working on `tCheck`. communicates via blue tooth with the device and we want to have a database where Android and iOS results are all in the same place incase a device error happened for something like a DFU. I just fixed this problem and can post the error I was getting if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `PhoneInfo` represents the current implementation of the type, so `oldObject` cannot be cast to `PhoneInfo`, because it represents the old `PhoneInfo` type, which doesn't exist anymore in the type system.

You could convert `oldObject` to `MigrationObject`, but you don't actually need to write any migration code, since `phoneInfo` has a default value, so `Realm` can simply assign the default value of `phoneInfo` to the variable during migration. You simply need to bump the schema version and you're fine.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 6,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 6 {
            // Realm can handle the migration automatically, no need to do anything
        }
})
let r = try! Realm()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this but taking out the line

```
let phoneInfo = oldObject!["phoneInfo"] as! PhoneInfo
```

did the trick for me. my AppDelegate now looks like:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 6,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 6) {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: TestResult.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    //changed
                    newObject!["phoneInfo"] = "iOS"
                }
            }
    })
    let r = try! Realm()
```